# Contact from Partner User are hidden from Partner Executives

Tags: sharing, contact, roles, role-hierarchy, partner

Here's my setup

- I create a new Dev Org.
- I did made Contacts Private internally and externally.
- I went in the *Community Settings* and set *Number of partner roles* to *3*
- I enabled Partner Relationship Management.
- I created a community and shared it with all users with the *Partner Community User* profile.
- I created an Account and enabled it as Partner.
- I made a contact and enabled a Partner user (*Partner Community User* Profile, *[AccountName] Partner Executive* role). Lets call him **PartnerExecutive**.
- I made a contact and enabled a Partner user (*Partner Community User* Profile, *[AccountName] Partner User* role). Lets call him **PartnerUser**.
- I logged in as PartnerUser and created a Contact. I filled the *Last Name* field only.
- I logged in as PartnerExecutive and went to see all Contacts.

What I expected: PartnerExecutive should see PartnerUser's contact, since PartnerUser reports to him in the hierarchy.

What happened: PartnerExecutive does not see PartnerUser's contact.

I tried with a *Case* object and it worked as expected (PartnerExecutive sees all PartnerUser owned Cases, with the object set as Private Externally and Internally)
Am I missing something here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, it appears that the "missing" Contact is not associated with an Account. Contacts without Accounts are treated as [**private**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=contacts_sharing_considerations.htm&type=5):

> A contact that isn’t linked to an account is always private, regardless of your organization’s sharing model. Only the owner of the contact and administrators can view it. **Sharing rules and workflow rules don’t apply to private contacts.** If your organization uses divisions, private contacts always belong to the global division.

Emphasis mine. To see the sharing rules applied, associate the Contact with an Account.